# Ruby automatically expands Hash into keyword arguments without double splat

Tags: ruby

The below Ruby code results in: `unknown keyword: a (ArgumentError)`:

```
def test(x={}, y: true); end

test({a:1})
```

Why? I would expect this to happen with `test(**{a:1})`, but I don't understand why my hash is being automagically expanded without the double splat.

Comment: `x` is optional and Ruby thinks you're passing kwargs (since `test(a:1)` and `test({a:1})` are equivalent, even before 2.x but back then it didn't matter). By the way, the default value could be even `[]` or `false`. There's also [a bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11068).

Comment: Yeah this is very strange and unintuitive. Glad it is being treated as a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since x is optional, hash moves over to kwarg argument.
Unspecified keywords raise error in that case:

```
def foo(name:)
  p name
end

foo # raises "ArgumentError: missing keyword: name" as expected
foo({name: 'Joe', age: 10}) # raises "ArgumentError: unknown keyword: age"
```

Check out [this](https://dev.firmafon.dk/blog/drat-ruby-has-a-double-splat/) article

Answer (score 1):

I'd also find it a bug as it behaves quite inconsistently, only for hashes with keys of `Symbol` type:

```
test({a:1})  # raises ArgumentError
test({'a' => 1})  # nil, properly assigned to optional argument x
method(:test).parameters
=> [[:opt, :x], [:key, :y]]
```

You may pass both arguments and it starts to assign them properly, but this is not a solution.

```
test({a:1}, {y:false})  # nil
```

Any reason why this is not a bug but an expected behavior ?